# How do I assign names to variables in an arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, excel

I am doing a project for my AP Computer Science class. The current project asks us to create a rip off version of excel that prints to the console. I am wondering if theres a way for me to create an arraylist of empty values that I can assign cell names to (A1, A2, F6, etc.) and then use those names to call values from their place in the arraylist. For example, I'd give the cell D4 a value of 6, store that 6 in an arraylist, then call it back using "D6".

A link to the directions of the project: https://issaquahwednet-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/personal/stutlerk_issaquah_wednet_edu/EQOW8BFzHIhIsdvXGP-qKDsBbN7BFa-kUCiMeeq9BZbbwg?e=Nc1Jcs

Maybe I'm not making sense, for which I am very sorry.

```
//what i would like to be able to do:
arraylist "cells" = (A1 through L20)
user input = "A1 = hi"
set index "A1" of "cells" to "hi"
repeat that stuff until user input = quit
```

is this possible? or would I just have to create two arraylists, one for cell numbers and one for values? I guess I could do that and then if a user wants to see what a cell says then they could Say "A1" and I could search my cell arraylist for a value of A1 then compare that index with the other arraylist.

I'm completely lost one this and, again, sorry if I'm not making any sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want, you'd need a map rather than a list. Lists always have integer numbers as the indices and there's no way to change that. (You could technically do this with two arrayLists, but it would be a pain to maintain it so that "A1" and "hi" stayed in the same index on two different lists if you ever had to delete/move anything.)

The HashMap documentation is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

And you'd do something like this:

```
Map<String, String> cells = new HashMap<String,String>();
cells.put("A1", "hi");
```

That would create a key-value pair with key "A1" and value "hi".

Comment: I see! Could I print the map inside the cell block? (we need to print a "cell" as | [10 spaces] |)
Meaning could I go through each cell value and print it in the place of a normally empty cell? How do I call an individual cell among the Map?

Comment: To get the value of a specific cell, you'd call `cells.get("A1");`. That'll return the value for that key, `"hi"`. If you call `cells.get("a key you haven't added");`, it'll return `null`. To print out one value and add the correct number of spaces, you'll have to use the `length()` method of a string to check the number of characters, and then make up the difference in spaces to get to 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can use structure `map` where for every key you have associated a value.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html